# Change Panel Type in Design Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have designed a Form class using a `TableLayoutPanel`.  It is looking how I want it too, but I realized while running the application that it flickers when re-sizing and swapping out panels.  So I created a new class, `DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel` using `TableLayoutPanel` as a base class.  I'm wondering if there is an easy way in the Visual Studio 2012 designer to swap out the two panels without having to completely redesign the form again.

Comment: Why not just set `DoubleBufferd = true` on the original panel?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: And what did you do in the derived Panel that you expect to make a difference?

Comment: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` Inside the constructor.

Comment: That's almost exactly what setting `DoubleBuffered = true` does already...

Comment: I know, that works better for me than just setting `DoubleBuffered = true`.  I'm not sure why, in my research as to what was going on, that was a suggested fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into the `designer.cs` file and change the types manually. Since the new type derives from the old type, it should work flawlessly.

Comment: I did try that, when the project rebuilds, it switches it back out to the `System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: You aren't changing all of the references then. Make sure you change every reference to `TableLayoutPanel` into a reference to `DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Ok, it worked the second time, I did a clean and rebuild before closing the designer.cs code and it stuck.  Thanks for your help!